# Most pythonic way to convert a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to convert a list of tuples in the style:

```
[(day1, name1, value1), (day2, name2, value2), (day3, name3, value3)]... etc
```

into:

```
[day1, day2, day3], [name1, name2, name3], [value1, value2, value3]... etc
```

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
vals is the list of tuples
day = []
name = []
value = []
for val in vals:
    day.append(val[0])
    name.append(val[1])
    value.append(val[2])
```

It works, but it looks pretty ugly... I'm wondering if there's a more "pythonic" way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list comprehension with the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is easiest:

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*list_of_tuples)]
```

This applies each separate tuple as an argument to `zip()` using the `*arguments` expansion syntax. `zip()` then pairs up each value from each tuple into new tuples.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('day1', 'name1', 'value1'), ('day2', 'name2', 'value2'), ('day3', 'name3', 'value3')]
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*list_of_tuples)]
[['day1', 'day2', 'day3'], ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']]
```

This forces the output to use lists; you can just use straight `zip()` if all you need is the 3-value combos:

```
>>> zip(*list_of_tuples)
[('day1', 'day2', 'day3'), ('name1', 'name2', 'name3'), ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')]
```

In Python 3, use `list(zip(*list_of_tuples))` or just loop over the output.

Comment: I really like the zip(*l)!

Comment: Wow, exactly what I need. Wasnt aware of this function. Why do I need the star though?

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha: To apply the *values* in the outer list as separate arguments to `zip()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see... Ok, thank you very much. I'll give you the correct answer as soon as I can